# Dojo Onchange event on hidden fields

Tags: javascript, html, events, dojo, nodelist

I have a drop down which may or may not change the value of a hidden field. The change is decided by a calculation function.
I want to track the change in the hidden field. If there is any change, I want to check a checkbox.

How can this be achieved?
I cannot change my HTML. Hence everything is has be handled in the JS.

```
<input type="hidden" name="03Text" value="">
```

In Java script:

```
var w = dojo.query('[type$=hidden]');
 w.forEach(function(node, index, nodelist){
       dojo.connect(node , "onchange", function(evt){                   
       controlapiObj.setControlAttribute(payload.srcFormId, payload.outputParams[0], true, "checked");  
       });          
});
```

I use dojo.query because there are many such hidden fields in the form, and I have to monitor the value change of all.

Answer (score 0):

*emphasized text*I believe the problem is with the the "onchange" event not firing when you programmatically change the value of the hidden field.  You can trigger this event manually the same time the value of the field is changed like so.  My example uses dojo 1.10 and the on function

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="03Text" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="03Text" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="03Text" value="3">
```

SCRIPT:

```
require(["dojo/query", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"], function(query, on){

var w = query('[type$=hidden]');
w.forEach(function(node, index, nodelist){
    on(node, "onchange", function(){
        console.log(node);
    })         
});

var event = new Event('onchange');
w[0].dispatchEvent(event);
w[1].dispatchEvent(event);
w[2].dispatchEvent(event);

})
```

Jsfiddle with example:

http://jsfiddle.net/kagant15/ay1dzqqg/